# Trouble understanding folds in Haskell

Tags: haskell

i want to have a function that takes a list and a number, and applies all functions in that list to the number.
For example:

```
applyAll [(*3),(+1),\x->x+5] 2
```

would result in the number 24.

My problem is that i have to do it with fold, and i don't understand it quite well yet. LearnYouaHaskell helped a little, but i'm still pretty confused.

Any help on how to do this ?

Comment: The trick is to return a new function from your callback that has one of its argument already applied to its other argument.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant that's the purpose os the function, what i was asking is for a practical solution, because i struggle with folds

Comment: a la "gimme teh codez" style? that's not something we like to do on Stack Overflow, but let me see…

Comment: @laker001 I also added an answer with a complete, compilable example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, lets think of the type of `applyAll`:

```
applyAll :: Num a => [(a -> a)] -> a -> a
```

In the process you create a single value from a list. This is called *folding* (or a *fold*). Your example suggests that `applyAll` should start from the right, since the result is

```
24 = 3 * (1 + (5 + (2)))
```

Therefore, it is a *right fold*. There are two functions in `Prelude` (and some variants) which fold a list: `foldl` and `foldr`. The suffix indicate whether it is a left or right fold. As discussed above, you want a right fold. Lets have a look on `foldr`'s type:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

The documentation indicates that `(a -> b -> b)` is the folding function, taking a value from the list (of type `a`) and an accumulator (of type `b`). Then follows the initial value, and last, the list.

A first prototype for `applyAll` is therefore

```
applyAll fns init = foldr ?? init fns
```

At this point we're only using the types. We know that `applyAll` takes a list as first argument, and a value as a second one. We know that `foldr` takes some kind of function, a value, and a list. So this first draft *just fits* our purpose.

We're now almost there! What's missing is the correct folding function. Remember, we're looking for something that takes a value from the list, and an accumulator. However, in our case, the list has values of type `(a -> a)`, and the accumulator is `a`. So our function should have type

```
?? :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

Luckily, that function is actually tremendously easy, well known, and probably often used by you. Think about it: the function should take another function, a value, and return a value. That sounds like a simple function application, and indeed `($)` is the function your looking for.

Putting all those things together to create `applyAll` is left to you as an exercise, but at this point, there isn't much left to do.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment: `fold` (or, as it's more commonly known, `reduce`) is a higher-order function that applies a two-argument transformation to each element of the list, the other argument being the return value of the previous transformation; hence "chaining" the transformation over all the elements of the list.

Using this logic, you can intuitively deduce that if you have a list of functions, your transform has to return another function. But what kind of function should it return? It turns out the transform can be the function composition operation itself.

Example (probably not very idiomatic, as I'm explicitly avoiding point-free notation - it may or may not help you understand the code more easily):

```
-- composes a list of functions, the last element in the list being the innermost
applyAll :: [Int -> Int] -> (Int -> Int)
applyAll fs = foldr (.) id fs

-- usage:
main :: IO ()
main = print $ applyAll [(*3), (+1), \x->x+5] 2
```